# Count(*) and Sum in the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum

I'm banging my head against the wall, here. I've looked at dozens of StackOverflow questions that are similar, and they get me close, but I haven't found one yet that does what I need.
I have thousands of questions in a database with answers from multiple users to each question. I need to aggregate the answers to show the count of distinct answers per question. That's the easy part; where I'm stumbling is in adding a Sum column to show the total number of answers given for each question. I can do it if I restrict the Where clause to specific questions, but I'm trying to get this all into one query if possible.
Here's the Query:

```
select c.ID, a.userID. c.question, a.answer, count(a.answer) as cnt
from NotableAnswers a, categories b, questions c
where c.fkCategory = b.ID and a.questionID = c.ID and b.ID = 18
Group By a.answer, c.ID, c.question
Order By c.ID, answer asc
```

What I need is a result set that looks like this

```
ID   | userID |  Question   |    Answer    |   cnt   |    totcnt
------------------------------------------------------------------
175  | 10318  |Favorite...  |Dropbox       |    15   |      35
175  | 10354  |Favorite...  |Box           |    2    |      35
175  | 10323  |Favorite...  |Google Drive  |    15   |      35
175  | 103111 |Favorite...  |Cubby         |    3    |      35
186  | 10318  |Best IDE...  |IntelliJ      |    4    |      12
186  | 103613 |Best IDE...  |Android Studio|    6    |      12
186  | 103117 |Best IDE...  |Eclipse       |    2    |      12
```

This set shows the Answer as an aggregate and the count of that specific answer along with the sum of the number of answers provided to each distinct question.

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, learn to use proper `join` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Second, the answer is window functions:

```
select q.ID, a.userID. q.question, a.answer, count(a.answer) as cnt,
       sum(count(a.answer)) over (partition by q.id) as total_cnt
from NotableAnswers a join
     questions q
     on a.questionID = q.ID join
     categories c 
     on q.fkCategory = c.ID 
where c.ID = 18
Group By a.answer, c.ID, c.question
Order By q.ID, answer asc;
```

In addition, it is better to use table aliases that are abbreviations for the table names rather than arbitrary letters.

Comment: Seriously too fast... i was just about to post this.

Comment: How is `a.userID` in the `SELECT` statement?  It isn't in the group by or an `AGGREGATE` function.

Comment: Thank you for the very quick answer and the gentle nudge toward proper syntax. I suppose, somewhere in there, I should have mentioned it's not my query, I've just inherited it. But, that's not germane to the issue and I did modify it, slightly to make the context a bit more clear, meaning, I did forget to include userID in the Group By. My bad. 

But, once again, thank you for the quick, accurate and very helpful response.